# SFTP (sublime_package): automatically upload CSS when only SASS has been saved

Tags: sublimetext2, sftp

I am using the SFTP sublime package from wbond.net to upload files directly to the server upon save. This works fine.

The issue is I have to go into the CSS file and save it for it to be uploaded (i.e. the SASS file that I edit is uploaded upon save, but the CSS - even though it has been changed - needs to be saved for it to be uploaded)

The options don't seem to allow this to happen, They are:

```
"save_before_upload": true,
"upload_on_save": true,
"sync_down_on_open": false,
"sync_skip_deletes": false,
"sync_same_age": true,
"confirm_downloads": false,
"confirm_sync": true,
"confirm_overwrite_newer": false,
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

Open the css output file in sublime, press "cmd+shift+p" (Mac), "ctrl+shift+p" (windows) search for SFTP and select "SFTP: Monitor File", then the css will be uploaded as soon as it is compile